# Table of contents in scrbook/komascript: add dots to chapter titles

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook, tocstyle

I need to customize the appearance of my table of contents according to the requirements of a publisher.

Here is a minimal example of what it looks like right now:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\part{First part}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second section}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

This produces something that looks like this:

---

[image: Screenshot of my current TOC]

---

Now my publisher requested that the **chapter** titles should have dots between title and page number.

I have found the `tocstyle` package, but I don't understand its documentation. I am not even sure the package lets me do what I need to do. Can somebody please make suggestions on how to get what I want? Thanks.

**Edit:** I need to remove the part page numbers as well. I posted this requirement in my original question, but multiple questions per thread were discouraged. However, later it turned out that this can actually make a difference also for the question asked here: If I use `tocstyle` to suppress page part numbers, this may affect the solutions posted here to get rid of the chapter dots.

Comment: Three questions at once, it would be easier if you split the questions leaving just one detail to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am asking this as a separate question now.

Comment: `\KOMAoption{chapterentrydots}{true}
%\addtokomafont{chapterentrydots}{\bfseries}` Remove `%` for extra horror.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work if I use ``tocstyle`` to customize other aspects of the TOC. Other ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not use package `tocloft` (mentioned in your own answer) together with a KOMA-Script class.

There is an KOMA-Script option to fill the space between the chapter title and the pagenumber in TOC with dots:

```
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill}
```

[image]

---

If the page numbers for the chapter headings should not be bold use

```
\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\mdseries}
```

It is also possible to remove the page number for the part headings from TOC:

```
\addtokomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrydotfill]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\nullfont}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\mainmatter
\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second section}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\end{document}
```

---

It is also possible to use package `tocstyle` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle. To get dots between the headings off all levels and the page numbers in TOC use

```
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
```

as already suggested by @Peter Ebelsberger. To remove the dots and the page numbers for the part headings in TOC add

```
\settocstylefeature[-1]{leaders}{\hfill}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberhook}{\nullfont}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{leaders}{\hfill}
\settocstylefeature[-1]{pagenumberhook}{\nullfont}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\mainmatter
\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second section}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Run several times to get

[image]

Comment: I believe this solution doesn't work if I use ``tocstyle`` to customize other aspects of the TOC. In my original question, I mentioned that I also needed to remove page numbers for parts, but Johannes_B said it was good practice to ask only one question per thread, so I removed this second requirement. Anyway, I need to make sure the part page numbers are gone as well, and if I use ``tocstyle`` to do that, this solution doesn't work anymore, I think.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! No need to load any additional packages, and both problems are solved at once!

Comment: Do not use package tocloft together with a KOMA-Script class. 

Why?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger `tocstyle` does the same (partly, but not everything) as KOMA, hence whacking KOMA-functionality to death. In other words, `tocloft` is good for customizing standard classes, but incompatible with KOMA-script.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

\mainmatter

\part{First part}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second section}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this also adds dots to part titles, right? That's not what I want.

Comment: What about Johannes' suggestion above? `\KOMAoption{chapterentrydots}{true}`

Comment: I believe Johannes_B's suggestion doesn't work if I use ``tocstyle`` to customize other aspects of the TOC. In my original question, I mentioned that I also needed to remove page numbers for parts, but Johannes_B said it was good practice to ask only one question per thread, so I removed this second requirement. Anyway, I need to make sure the part page numbers are gone as well, and if I use ``tocstyle`` to do that, this solution doesn't work anymore, I think.

Comment: @SpammerSlammer I thought we already had the question how to get the dos for chapterentries, but nothing really fitted. If so, we could have marked this (single) question as a duplicate. But esdd provided wverything in her answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this elsewhere:

```
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
\let\partbackup\l@part  % create a backup copy of the part definition
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{\partbackup{#1}{}}  % redefine part in order to leave out the page number for part
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}  % add dots for chapter entries
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}  % add dots for chapter entries
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}  % define chapter page numbers to be printed in normal font, not bold
```

Would people agree that this is a good solution, or are there side-effects I am not aware of?

Comment: See [comment above/below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292882/table-of-contents-in-scrbook-komascript-add-dots-to-chapter-titles?noredirect=1#comment709425_292893) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With the new `tocloft`, it works as follows:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
]{chapter}{chapter}
```